# How to make array inside array data for custom jQuery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for some tutorial to make an array data in custom jQuery Function, but I can't find any. Can you tell me how to make an array inside in array for jQuery Function? I want to call my function like this :

```
$(this).myPlugin({ 
    data_first: '1',
    data_second: {
       first_word : 'Hello', second_word : 'World'
    }
});
```

**my function script**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(data) {
       return this.each(function() {
          alert(data['data_first']+' bla bla '+ data['data_second'][first_word]);
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You are missing quotes around `first_word` on line 4 of your second code snippet

Answer (score 1):

That's called an object, not an array, and you can just access it `object1.object2_name.object3_name`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return this.each(function() {
            console.log(data.data_first + ' blah - ' + data.data_second.first_word);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you forgot to either enclose `first_word` in quotes or you accidentally used square brackets instead of the dot operator.

Adding the quotes:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(data) {
       return this.each(function() {
          alert(data['data_first']+' bla bla '+ data['data_second']['first_word']);
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Or using the dot operator (looks cleaner in my opinion):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(data) {
       return this.each(function() {
          alert(data.data_first + ' bla bla ' + data.data_second.first_word);
       });
    }
})(jQuery);
```